# Couldn't create error file for command: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, centos

When launching `tclsh`, I am getting this error message:

> couldn't create error file for command: no such file or directory

Can't find out what causes this to happen. How to fix this issue?

My host is running 64 bit CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

From the [comp.lang.tcl mailing list](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Tcl/comp.lang.tcl/2008-11/msg00890.html):

> For stderr, exec creates a tempfile into which all the (putative)
>   stderr-output goes, and which is read back afterwards.

I suggest following the rest of the info in that post.  For example, do you have a `.tclsh` file?  What is being run in it?

`strace tclsh` should give you enough info to determine where tcl is trying and failing to create a tempfile.